# magazines/webpages about city/commuting/folding bicycles

Tags: commuter, touring, commuting-bike, bags, city

In any shop you can find magazines about **sport** road or MTB, same about webpages or forums.

However, I find really difficult to find good pages about bicycles focused in  daily mobility/transportation. And I've never seen a paper magazine about this subject.

What is the expected information? Similar to what the road/MTB magazines cover.

- Analysis of some new bicycle models
- Product Comparatives
- Analysis of Accessories (more focused in mobility)
- Opinion articles
- Repairing and Mechanics articles...
- More mobility means (ebikes, touring, scotters, public cycles,sustainable transportation,..)
- ...

**Do you know good informative webpages, paper/pdf magazines, good twitter accounts, or videos channels about the mobility subject?**

Comment: bicycles.stackexchange.com is a very good resource to get answers to specific questions.

Comment: :D obviously I know about this service but the approach is different. When you read a newspaper/magazine , you can discover content/information about question/matters that you were not aware or previously interested in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not meet a Bicycles Stack Exchange guideline.